# Rename items on python list by list index

Tags: python, list

I have a list where I need to rename some items. However, let's assume that I don't know the items exact names as they are being added to the list as variables (in this cases I don't know the calendar week number).

```
myList = ['id', 'brandName', 'EngagedUsers_Week_47', 'EngagedUsers_Week_48', 'EngagedUsers_Week_49', 'EngagedUsers_Week_50', 'Week_47_VS_Week_48', 'Week_48_VS_Week_49', Week_49_VS_Week_50']
```

I need to convert the above list to:

```
myNewList = ['id', 'name', 'Week47', 'Week48', 'Week49', 'Week50', '47VS48', '48VS49', '49VS50']
```

I tried the below, but it would only work if I know the exact list item name :

```
for item in myList:
   if (item != "Users_Week_48"):
        myNewList.append("Week48")
   else:
        myNewList.append(item)
```

How can I solve my problem? Would this be something to do with going by list index and use regex? Could someone help please (I have very little knowledge on how this could be achieved) thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain more the conversion rule that you want to apply? It's not that clear.

Comment: I think it's time to read a tutorial on regular expressions; that will be the way to go here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this suffice?

```py
myList = ['id', 'brandName', 'EngagedUsers_Week_47', 'EngagedUsers_Week_48', 'EngagedUsers_Week_49',
          'EngagedUsers_Week_50', 'Week_47_VS_Week_48', 'Week_48_VS_Week_49', 'Week_49_VS_Week_50']

myNewList = []
for item in myList:
    if item[:2] == 'id':
        myNewList.append(item)
    elif item == 'brandName':
        myNewList.append('name')
    elif item[:12] == 'EngagedUsers':
        myNewList.append(item[13:17]+item[-2:])
    elif item[:4] == 'Week':
        myNewList.append(item[5:7]+item[8:10]+item[-2:])

print(myNewList)
```

```
['id', 'name', 'Week47', 'Week48', 'Week49', 'Week50', '47VS48', '48VS49', '49VS50']
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying for something readable and manageable (and extensible if later needed):

```
def convert(s):
    if s == 'brandName':
        return 'name'
    s = re.sub(r'EngagedUsers', '', s.replace('_', ''))
    s = re.sub(r'Week(\d+VS)Week(\d+)', r'\1\2', s)
    return s
```

```
[convert(s) for s in myList]

# out:
['id',
 'name',
 'Week47',
 'Week48',
 'Week49',
 'Week50',
 '47VS48',
 '48VS49',
 '49VS50']
```

Comment: I think this is a nice solution. Little extra: One could also use a functional approach here and use `map(convert, myList)`  or `list(map(convert, myList))`. Could be faster/more readable, depending on the problem

Comment: @user8408080: Well, I'm in [Guido's camp](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) on that one.  And trust me, I love the beauty of a well-crafted distributed map-reduce code to tackle large scale problems (petabytes), there were years in my life (over a decade ago) when trying to express any problem in map-reduce became a sort of sport...  But still, it's hard to deny list comprehensions a superiority when it comes to readability.

Comment: Well thank you for the interesting blog post :D I think this is more of a personal/company preference thing. For such simple things I most often use `map`, because *for me* it's more readable, but Guido really makes a point, that things could get too complicated. I'm still undecided on this one tbh :D